# Jquery slideToggle & Cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

im still fairly new to jquery and i got this slideToggle container,
but now i want to save a cookie if the container is hidden or not so
if one refreshes the page it keeps its current state.

I heard about the jquery cookie plugin but didn't really understand it to be honest. :(

Can anyone help me out?

My code so far is pretty simple:

```
$(function(){
 $("#hideslide").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });
});
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery Cookie plugin ([found here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js)) is the easiest way to use cookies with jQuery.

To set a cookie, this will do:

```
$.cookie("name", "content");
```

Getting a cookie is just as simple:

```
$.cookie("name");
```

So you should check on page load if the cookie is set:

```
if($.cookie("name") != null) {
    // Cookie set, action here
}
```

And on clicking the item to toggle, check if cookie is set. If it is set, remove it, else, set it:

```
if($.cookie("name") != null) {
    $.cookie("name", null); (null as value will remove the cookie)
}
else {
    $.cookie("name", "content");
}
```

I use this plugin myself and this is all you need. Easy.

Comment: Could you show me an example how it would look on my code? Sorry but i'm really new to all this :/

Comment: @Sev http://jsfiddle.net/ErhLu/ > the current content of the cookie is alerted on click ;) See how easy it is? null means that the cookie does not exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! Somehow this messes up my other jquery code i got, cause the slideToggle is wrapped around a jquery content slider :/ I hope i can figure it out somehow. Thanks again for helping

Comment: So the problem is that the slider is in another slider? Are you using IDs to slide it? Please provide a JSfiddle with an example.

Comment: Well im just using a plugin called "bxslider" for the content slider/slideshow. And around that my slideToggle container is wrapped. Heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PYxPa/

Comment: The sliding looks OK to me. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I'm running this on a vbulletin forum in the header template and i want the user to choose if the slider is hidden or shown. It works fine but when i refresh the site it changes back to the "shown" state. I want to use cookies to make it still hidden even when you refresh the page. :(

Comment: Thanks for helping again! It still doesn't work in my template. I got so much jquery code in there, i don't even know if its all correct >.< Everything works but when i add your code ALL jquery elements stop working. :(

Comment: This is my whole jquery code. (i know it's messed up, don't laugh at me please D:) http://jsfiddle.net/ub49L/   The last 2 functions are the slider and the slideToggle container

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13377/discussion-between-rune-and-sev)

Answer (score 0):

If your client browser targets are IE8+, you could, and I think should, use `localStorage` for this.

```
localStorage.setItem('mySlideState', "open");
```

Then test:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('mySlideState') == 'open') {
    //do stuff
}
```

You would achieve this through the callback on slideToggle

```
$('#highSlide').slideToggle(function () {
    //set localStorage to value here
});
```

Mozilla docs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage